# Форма и обработка данных на wordpress

Tags: wordpress, html-form

Код формы

```
<form action="<?php echo get_permalink(108);?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" title="Ваше Имя" name="name" />&nbsp;*<br />
    <input type="text" title="Ваши контакты" name="contact" />&nbsp;*<br />
    <textarea name="description" title="Примечание"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить" />
</form>
```

Шаблон страницы обработки этой формы

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: Обработка заказа
*/
    get_header();
    get_sidebar();
?>
    <div id="content">
        <?php
            if($_POST['submit']) {
                echo '<h1>Пришли данные!</h1>';
            }
        ?>
    </div>
<?php
    get_footer();
?>
```

Страница сама по себе открывается...Но когда отправляешь данные формы пишет ошибку что страница не найдена. Скажите в чем дело может быть?

Comment: Сравните адреса страниц, которая с формой и которая открывается после сабмита - они идентичны?

Comment: Форма стоит на постах, а вот обрабатывается отдельной страницей. Если после сабмита нажать на адр строку и перейти то страница открывается без проблем.

Comment: На саму себя отправляет кстати. А почему с поста на стр не идет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Была такая же проблема. Проблема просто смешная: нельзя использовать поля с name="name" - это имя зарезервировано Wordpress.
Замени например на name="**u**name" и все заработает.

И еще, если обработчик формы - та же страница, то `action="<?php echo get_permalink(108);?>"`  - лишнее.